How to bundle my NextJS React component only so I can inject it in any website?
I am using NextJS 14.2.3 and I want this test component which depends on the tailwindcss and react to be injected in a Wordpress/any kind of website.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Test() {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className='bg-blue-100 p-8'>
        <button onClick={() => setIndex(index + 1)}>Click</button>
        {index}
    </div>
  )
}


Below is the directory tree of how the result I want to be.
frontend/
├── app/
│   └── test.tsx
├── public/
│   └── test-bundle.js
├── package.json
└── next.config.mjs


Why?
I want to understand on the most basic level, how to do this because I have tickets component which depends on Stripe, Tailwind, lucide-react and NextJS server actions (which communicate with my backend). Which should be injectable in every website, the backend will take care of CORS.
I have been reading blogs, documentations and chating with chatGPT 4 about how to achieve this.
I've tried using webpack, which compiled the test component in the /public directory but when i tried to inject it in plain vanilla website but I got console errors which I tried to resolve but it still didn't work.

How exactly are you attempting to “inject” the element? What does Next.js have anything to do with a rather simple React component? What console errors are you seeing? Generally I would say this particular stack isn’t intended to be used in this way so while it may be possible, it may cause a lot more headaches for you than it’s worth - as such I would really be evaluating whether Next specifically is strictly necessary here

which I tried to resolve but it still didn't work <-- It will be a lot easier to help you if you actually show what you have tried.

On re-read: NextJS server actions requires this to run in a very specific way, which “injecting” to any random web page will not handle for you - can you explain how you think it should work in practice? I think you’re in need of a re-think of your target architecture.

@super My first post on the stack, forgive me. I honestly didn't know where to start showing what I had done.

@AdrianJ Forgive you... sarcasm I assume? I was just trying to give you some feedback.

@super Why do I feel bad haha but yes, I've tried so many things that I didn't know what to show. Thank you for the feedback, honestly.

To achieve an injectable React component from a Next.js project that can be used in any existing website, I followed these steps. My component depended on various libraries like React, Stripe, Radix-UI, Stripe, and even Next.js server actions. I will showcase only the ticket.tsx component as I use this project for commercial purposes.
Here's how I accomplished it:
Below is the structure of my parent component located in app/(marketing)/tickets. This component includes server actions, child components, and relies on libraries like Radix-UI:
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Steps from './steps';
import Step from './step';
import { Calendar } from '@/components/ui/calendar';
import TicketsCalculator from './ticketsCalculator';
import { useTicketStore } from '@/hooks/useTicketStore';
import { hr } from 'date-fns/locale';
import TicketsGuest from './ticketsGuest';
import TicketsPayment from './ticketsPayment';

export default function Tickets() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const date = useTicketStore(state => state.date);
  const setDate = useTicketStore(state => state.setDate);

  const handleIndex = (e: number): void => {
    setActiveIndex(e);
  };

  const steps = [
    { label: 'Select date', description: 'Select the date of your desired trip day' },
    { label: 'Tickets', description: 'Enter ticket numbers and information' },
    { label: 'Guest Info', description: 'Provide guest details' },
    { label: 'Payment', description: 'Complete payment for your tickets' },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="relative h-full w-full rounded-2xl bg-neutral-50 flex flex-col antialiased">
      <div className="p-4 md:p-6 z-50 w-full h-full flex flex-col">
        <Steps model={steps} activeIndex={activeIndex} onSelect={(e) => handleIndex(e)} />
        {activeIndex === 0 && (
          <Step activeIndex={activeIndex} changeActiveIndex={(e) => handleIndex(e)}>
            <Calendar
              mode="single"
              numberOfMonths={3}
              selected={date}
              onSelect={setDate}
              locale={hr}
              className="rounded-2xl w-fit mx-auto border bg-white hidden md:block"
            />
          </Step>
        )}
        {activeIndex === 1 && (
          <Step activeIndex={activeIndex} changeActiveIndex={(e) => handleIndex(e)}>
            <TicketsCalculator />
          </Step>
        )}
        {activeIndex === 2 && (
          <TicketsGuest activeIndex={activeIndex} changeActiveIndex={(e) => handleIndex(e)} />
        )}
        {activeIndex === 3 && (
          <TicketsPayment activeIndex={activeIndex} changeActiveIndex={(e) => handleIndex(e)} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Webpack Configuration
To bundle the Tickets component into a JavaScript file (tickets-bundle.js) that can be injected into other websites, I used Webpack. Here's the webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Load environment variables from .env
const env = dotenv.config().parsed || {};

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/(marketing)/tickets/tickets.tsx', // Entry point for the Tickets component
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'tickets-bundle.js', // Bundled file name
    library: {
      name: 'TicketsComponent', // Global variable name
      type: 'umd', // Universal Module Definition
    },
    globalObject: 'this', // Ensure compatibility in different environments
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/, // Handle TypeScript and TSX files
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i, // Process CSS files
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname), // Alias for project root
    },
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React', // Use React from the host environment
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM', // Use ReactDOM from the host environment
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser', // Polyfill for Node.js process
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(env), // Inject environment variables
    }),
  ],
  mode: 'production', // Build mode
};



Building the Bundle
Required packages: npm install dotenv process @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-typescript babel-loader css-loader style-loader webpack webpack-cli 
to run webpack so it can build the bundle using this command:
npx webpack --mode production

This creates the tickets-bundle.js file in the public directory.
Testing if works
Basically, to test, I've created a test folder on my laptop which has 2 files, index.html and tickets-bundle.js which the code I've copied from the one that Webpack has created. The index.html looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tickets Component</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/tickets-bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tickets-root"></div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      if (typeof TicketsComponent !== "undefined" && TicketsComponent.default) {
        ReactDOM.render(
          React.createElement(TicketsComponent.default),
          document.getElementById("tickets-root")
        );
      } else {
        console.error("TicketsComponent is not defined. Make sure tickets-bundle.js is loaded properly.");
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>


In production, instead of having
 <script src="/tickets-bundle.js"></script> 

it will be
<script src="https://my-domain.com/tickets-bundle.js"></script> 

which will allow me to inject the tickets component in the existing website that the client has.

How is it that this solution covers the Server Actions you mention in your original post? It’s not immediately clear from what you’ve provided here.

One of the child components, such as ticketsGuest.tsx imports a server action import { createDraftReservation } from '@/app/actions/publicActions'  which depends on process.env `"use server"
import { Product, ReservationDraft } from "@/types/models";
const API = process.env.API_URL;
export async function createDraftReservation(request: string) {
var response = await fetch(`${API}reservations/draft`, {
    method: 'POST',

...
}` (I can't post all of the code since it wont fit in the comment).
